# DataType on TreeView

Tags: wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2012, data-binding

I'm trying to make some data binding on a TreeView in a WPF solution. However, I can't seem to figure it out.

my XAML is as follows:

```
<Window x:Class="NoteNest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Note Nest" Height="512" Width="756">
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
        <StackPanel Width="190">
            <TreeView HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" BorderThickness="0" SelectedItemChanged="NoteSelect" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Name="Nest">
                <TreeView.Resources>
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Note}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                </TreeView.Resources>

            </TreeView>
        </StackPanel>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

I keep getting the error:

> Note is not supported in a Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) project.

For the record. I have a public class named Note in the same namespace, so ether I have completely misunderstood how DataType works, or I'm just missing something.

What do I do?

Comment: the `Note` is in some namespace which is not declared in XAML code. Such as when you create a new WpfApplication, normally the default namespace (which may be where you declare your class Note) is `WpfApplication1`.

Comment: You forgot to qualify the `Note` with the namespace. You need to declare a `xmlns` for Note's namespace and use it as `yournamespace:Note`.

Comment: Okay, that solved that problem. My bindings is still not working though. Should I make a new question for that?